# Why is this batch code running erroneously (for /f)

Tags: batch-file, csv

I have a batch code that is not running as expected.

Here is the code:

```
@echo off

FOR /F "eol=- tokens=1-11 delims=," %%A IN (1.csv) DO IF %%D==6038000006 ECHO %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G,%%H,%%I,%%J,%%K >> 6038000006.csv
FOR /F "eol=- tokens=1-11 delims=," %%A IN (2.csv) DO IF %%D==6038000006 ECHO %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G,%%H,%%I,%%J,%%K >> 6038000006.csv
FOR /F "eol=- tokens=1-11 delims=," %%A IN (3.csv) DO IF %%D==6038000006 ECHO %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G,%%H,%%I,%%J,%%K >> 6038000006.csv
FOR /F "eol=- tokens=1-11 delims=," %%A IN (10.csv) DO IF %%D==6038000006 ECHO %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G,%%H,%%I,%%J,%%K >> 6038000006.csv
FOR /F "eol=- tokens=1-11 delims=," %%A IN (111.csv) DO IF %%D==6038000006 ECHO %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G,%%H,%%I,%%J,%%K >> 6038000006.csv
FOR /F "eol=- tokens=1-11 delims=," %%A IN (112.csv) DO IF %%D==6038000006 ECHO %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G,%%H,%%I,%%J,%%K >> 6038000006.csv
FOR /F "eol=- tokens=1-11 delims=," %%A IN (113.csv) DO IF %%D==6038000006 ECHO %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G,%%H,%%I,%%J,%%K >> 6038000006.csv
FOR /F "eol=- tokens=1-11 delims=," %%A IN (114.csv) DO IF %%D==6038000006 ECHO %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G,%%H,%%I,%%J,%%K >> 6038000006.csv
FOR /F "eol=- tokens=1-11 delims=," %%A IN (121.csv) DO IF %%D==6038000006 ECHO %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G,%%H,%%I,%%J,%%K >> 6038000006.csv
FOR /F "eol=- tokens=1-11 delims=," %%A IN (122.csv) DO IF %%D==6038000006 ECHO %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G,%%H,%%I,%%J,%%K >> 6038000006.csv
FOR /F "eol=- tokens=1-11 delims=," %%A IN (123.csv) DO IF %%D==6038000006 ECHO %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G,%%H,%%I,%%J,%%K >> 6038000006.csv
```

The result is that is processes items from `1.csv` then skips `2.csv` and `3.csv` and goes straight to `10.csv`, `111.csv`, `112.csv`, `113.csv`, `114.csv`, `121.csv`, `122.csv` and `123.csv`.

#### Edit

So here is the thing; I am doing this before I tried the code above.

1. I create an empty file with filename `6038000006.csv`.
2. I ran this code:

   ```
   @echo off

   FOR /F "eol=- tokens=1-11 delims=," %%A IN (1.csv) DO IF %%D==6038000006 ECHO %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G,%%H,%%I,%%J,%%K >> 6038000006.csv
   ```
3. The `6038000006.csv` gets filled with data (actually the data is dated file [`1.csv` is 1st quarter of the year, `2.csv` is 2nd quarter of the year] per line so I am pretty sure its in order).
4. And then I run this code again editing `1.csv` to become `2.csv`:

   ```
   @echo off

   FOR /F "eol=- tokens=1-11 delims=," %%A IN (2.csv) DO IF %%D==6038000006 ECHO %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G,%%H,%%I,%%J,%%K >> 6038000006.csv
   ```
5. Since the code `>>` appends data at the bottom of the file. I do not think it overlaps but rather appends to the last data.
6. I repeat number 4 until I complete `123.csv`.
7. At the end of my repeating run, the `6038000006.csv` contains all the filtered data from files `1.csv` to file `123.csv`.
8. Now I figured, if it was possible to consolidate the code from `1.csv` instead of single lines prompting me to code (of course I transferred the `6038000006.csv` elsewhere and created a "new" blank `6038000006.csv` for this experimental code (same as above)).

However, the result is that the data that comes from `2.csv` and `3.csv` is not reflected on the new `6038000006.csv`.

Comment: user3771531, as per my answer, you should comment out the echo off statement to see what it's actually doing. In addition, the dir commands I proffered will show what each loop is doing to the output file.

Comment: Thanks! Will inform you once I hit it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up, you need to figure out if it's *actually* skipping the files (you don't provide support for this contention so we're unsure what's making you think that). Comment out the `echo off` with:

```
rem @echo off
```

and then run it. The commands executed should be echoed before execution.

Second, check that the files being "skipped" actually *have* some lines where the fourth column is `6038000006`. It may be that they're not being skipped but instead don't have the required data in them.

Another option would be to insert:

```
dir 6038000006.csv
```

after each `for` loop to see how the file is changing.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I actually ran a manual filtering :( took me time so that I can validate the run made by the .bat file. I did it by doing it file by file. Meaning, I started with only 1.csv then 2.csv and so on. I compared it by doing the above code. The results on the "consolidated" did not contain anything from 2.csv and 3.csv. From there, I concluded that it's actually skipping.

Comment: @user3771531, I'm not sure what you're stating there. Are you saying you compared the output of the above script with some other manual process you did? If so, how sure are you that the manual process was correct? :-)

Comment: Suggest you also show us some sample (complete) lines containing the correct %%D field from both 1.csv and 2.csv.

Comment: My validation was that i did this code - @echo off

FOR /F "eol=- tokens=1-11 delims=," %%A IN (1.csv) DO IF %%D==6038000006 ECHO %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G,%%H,%%I,%%J,%%K >> 6038000006.csv ----------eleven times for each file 1.csv, 2.csv, 3.csv and dumped the results into a single file so that i can compare with the consolidated one :(

Comment: So, where did this consolidated file come from? And, if you did it manually, what are the chances you simply mistyped 6038000006 for a couple of them? I'm trying to establish the two paths you took to get the data you're comparing, and how accurate they may have been.

Comment: Still need to see sample lines from the working and non-working file, along with your confirmation of what happens when the echo-off is commented out.

Comment: I'll be editing the file above for a more detailed one :) Thanks for the comments. Please see above in a while.

Comment: No probs, @user3771531, the more info the better :-)